# Controls not showing up when added or doubling

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two textboxes for entering the name and price of an item, a submit button under it, and a bulleted list under that that shows the current items.
On clicking the submit button the new item should be entered in the list of items and the bulleted list refreshed with the new items.

What happens though is that if I put the code that generates the bulleted list in OnInit then the list isn't refreshed on the first postback. If I put it in Page_Load then the list just duplicates itself on every postback. Where am I supposed to put it and what am i doing wrong?

Here is my code.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    List<Product> Products = (List<Product>)Session["Products"];
    foreach (Product p in Products)
    {
        ListItem productname = new ListItem();
        productname.Text = p.name;
        blProducts.Items.Add(productname);
    }

}
```

Here is the code of the submit button:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Product> Products = (List<Product>)Session["Products"];
    string name = txtName.Text;
    decimal price = decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
    Product p = new Product(name, price);
    Products.Add(p);
    Session["Products"] = Products;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postback of the buttonclick happens AFTER init, so your order of events is:

1. Init adds 1 listitem for products
2. Button click happens, adding to products.

Since products is enumerated before the new item is added, it isn't reflected on your page.

[Asp.Net Page Lifecycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

you could move the init code to prerender, since that's the first event after handling postbacks.  It may be doubling because you're never clearing that list of items, which, i believe, are stored in ViewState, so every time init gets called (every request), you are adding all of `Products` again.  You could also wrap that section in an `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` and add directly to the list & the session in your button click, but it's probably better to fix the logic than duplicate the addition code.

Answer (score 1):

Do

Page.IsPostBack == false.

Use:

```
page_load {
if(!Page.IsPostback)
  CalltheLoadFunction

}

on_click {
_adds the stuff.
CalltheLoadFunction() //again
}

CalltheLoadFunction() {
 dropdown.clear().
 dropdown.datasource = datasource
 dropddown.databind()
}
```

I wouldn't use Init. I use Page_load (ispostback false) in that function. After the button click, call the refresh data function again. You should check ispostback on the page load function all the time. Make sure it is false so that it doesn't load again.

Comment: What the problem is in using !IsPostBack is that i have some user controls on the same page that have buttons on them and when i press those buttons i have to refresh the page because they change some stuff (i have Response.Redirect("Default.aspx") in them). And then every time i press those buttons in the user controls the IsPostBack is false.

Comment: If you are coming back to the same page, don't use Response.Redirect() which makes postback false. Call the load function again after the update and it will be postback = false. Unless you are going to a different page, you shouldn't redirect back to the same page. Calling a function will send it back to the server with postback true.

Comment: You mean call the load function from the user control? I thought that you cant call functions from the parent page in user controls?

Comment: The page loads. You click add -> 1. clear the items in the dropdown first, and then add the items to the dropdown. I think you have to clear the items from the dropdown after every on_click, otherwise it is going to keep adding. See above.